# Reuse layouts and fragments

Tags: android

Lets say that in my app i have 2 screens with exactly the same views, the only thing that changes are the texts.

Whats the best way to be more efficient here?

1. Using the same layout with the same fragment and same VM? And handle
   all the texts logic in the VM
2. Use the same layout but with different fragment and different VM?

For me, if the screens are 100% the same but the only thing that changes are the texts i would go with the first option but im not sure thats the correct way to do it.

Comment: go with the first option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say go with option 1 if everything is same other than string changes. You can have a flag and based on that flag you can update strings.